# Only accept numbers with one decimal place

Tags: python, rounding

The user should only be allowed to enter a number between 1.0 and 4.0 with one decimal place.

```
number = input() # 3.7 allowed
                 # 3.77 not allowed
```

Furthermore, if 3.77 is passed, it should try again the input.

What I tried:

```
while True:
    number = float(input())
    if number >= 1.0 and number <= 4.0:
        break
number = round(number, 1)
```

**I don't want to use** `round(number, 1)`.

Also I am not allowed to import any modules except `math`.

Comment: I put in an answer with `re` module.. but do you mean you don't want to use ANY modules even ones in the standard library?

Comment: Yes, it's a school work and I am not allowed to import any modules except `matplotlib`, `geodist` and `math`..

Comment: Do you have any problem if you use `math` library in your code?

Comment: `math` is allowed but I didn't used it yet :)

Comment: Well with `math`... `if number == (math.floor(number*10)/10):` could work.

Comment: Check the answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `math` library.

```
import math
def Truncate(f, n):
    return math.floor(f*10**n)/10**n
while True:
    number = float(input())
    if number == Truncate(number,1) and number >= 1.0 and number <= 4.0:
        break
```

Comment: Why `(f*10**n)/10**n` and not `(f*10)/10`? I tried the last one and it's working fine tho :)

Comment: in your case n is 1 so there is no difference between `math.floor(f*10**n)/10**n` and `math.floor(f*10)/10`

Answer (score 1):

Easier to just match the string before converting to `float`:

```
import re

while True:
    s = input()
    if re.match(r'^\d+(\.\d)?$', s):
        number = float(s)
        break
```

How the regular expression works:

`^` = start of string

`\d+` = one or more digits

`(\.\d)?` = optionally a period + one more digit

`$` = end of string